# Objective-C enum not recognized in Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I have a delegate method that passes an enum as an argument:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: JTTableViewGestureRecognizer!, commitEditingState state: JTTableViewCellEditingState, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void {
    //....
}
```

The enum is JTTableViewCellEditingState. It's implementation is in the same header file as the delegate method. It's as follows:

```
typedef enum {
    JTTableViewCellEditingStateMiddle,
    JTTableViewCellEditingStateLeft,
    JTTableViewCellEditingStateRight,
} JTTableViewCellEditingState;
```

Yet trying to reference a state, for example Left, gives an error:

```
if state == JTTableViewCellEditingState.Left {
```

> 'JTTableViewCellEditingState.Type' does not have a member named 'Left'

Trying to do it the old, Objective-C way, like some kind of peasant, gives me a different, more expected, error:

```
if state == JTTableViewCellEditingStateLeft {
```

> Cannot invoke '==' with an argument list of type '(JTTableViewCellEditingState, JTTableViewCellEditingState)'

I'm wondering how I should overcome this issue? I believe referencing Objective-C enums has worked just fine in the past.

Answer (score 3):

This type of enum decleration causes problems in swift. I had similar problem. My solution is to create a helper objective-c method that does comparison and use that method in swift whenever == is needed.

Other solution may be refactor that code if you can and convert it proper enum decleration in objective-c.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum) {
    MyEnumValue1,
    MyEnumValue2
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you use `NS_ENUM` instead? And then try `JTTableViewCellEditingState.JTTableViewCellEditingStateLeft` or even `.JTTableViewCellEditingStateLeft` to access your enum. If you can't change it to `NS_ENUM`, please have a look at  [Using non NS_ENUM objective-C enum in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24948082/using-non-ns-enum-objective-c-enum-in-swift)

Answer (score 2):

In my environment - Xcode Version 6.1.1 (6A2006):

```
typedef enum {
    JTTableViewCellEditingStateMiddle,
    JTTableViewCellEditingStateLeft,
    JTTableViewCellEditingStateRight,
} JTTableViewCellEditingState;
```

is exported to Swift as:

```
struct JTTableViewCellEditingState {
    init(_ value: UInt32)
    var value: UInt32
}
var JTTableViewCellEditingStateMiddle: JTTableViewCellEditingState { get }
var JTTableViewCellEditingStateLeft: JTTableViewCellEditingState { get }
var JTTableViewCellEditingStateRight: JTTableViewCellEditingState { get }
```

So, this should works:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: JTTableViewGestureRecognizer!, commitEditingState state: JTTableViewCellEditingState, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void {
    if state.value == JTTableViewCellEditingStateLeft.value {
        // ...
    }
}
```